# Specify subclass when declaring abstract class

Tags: kotlin

kotlin version: 1.3.50

In sample code, I want to use `compareTo` method to compare only between the same subclass's instances like `dog` is compared to only `dog`.

I think it would be better if `compareTo` accepted only subclass but `Animal`. But I don't know how to do. Is there a good idea?

```
abstract class Animal{
    abstract fun compareTo(other: Animal)
    // I want to implement like `abstract fun compareTo(other: this::class)`
}

class Dog: Animal(){
    override fun compareTo(other: Animal) {
        assert(other is Dog)
        // do something
    }
}

class Cat: Animal(){
    override fun compareTo(other: Animal) {
        assert(other is Cat)
        // do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a self-referring type parameter to `Animal` class:

```
abstract class Animal<SELF : Animal<SELF>> {
    abstract fun compareTo(other: SELF): Int
}
```

Now you can extend it like this:

```
class Dog : Animal<Dog>() {
    override fun compareTo(other: Dog): Int {
        // do something
    }
}
```